# How to add date when radio is selected and form submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Im trying to build some JS to add a date in format dd-MoN-yyyy (10-OCT-2017) when certain radios are selected and submitted.  Below is a basic skeleton of my form:

```html
<html>
<body>
      <form method="post" action="https://sample.sample.com" onsubmit="return setform(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ_DATE" value="">
      <input type="radio" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ" value="D" id="daily"> 
      <input type="radio" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ" value="W" id="weekly"> 
      <input type="radio" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ" value="B" id="biweekly">    
      <input type="radio" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ" value="A" id="all">    
      <input type="image" src="sample.submit.button" name="submit" value="submit" class="bnt" id="subBtn"></td>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So whenever a **OPT_DOWN_FREQ** radio it selected, we should submit **dd-MoN-yyyy** to field **OPT_DOWN_FREQ_DATE**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add a change listener to the radio button group. From there you can add a handler to add the value of the selected radio button to the input you need it at.

Depending on how you plan to pass around the date information, you can format it before setting the radio input values, or during runtime.

A few things to note: don't forget to add your self-closing tags, and you also have a random /td lurking around there.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ"]').change(function(){
   var dateString = this.value;
    // format dateString as needed, if dateString is a timestamp. 
   $('input[name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ_DATE"]').val(dateString); // Set the value of OPT_DOWN_FREQ_DATE 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="https://sample.sample.com" onsubmit="return setform(this);">
      <input type="text" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ_DATE" value=""/>
      <input type="radio" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ" value="D" id="daily"/> 
      <input type="radio" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ" value="W" id="weekly"/> 
      <input type="radio" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ" value="B" id="biweekly"/>    
      <input type="radio" name="OPT_DOWN_FREQ" value="A" id="all"/>
      <input type="image" src="sample.submit.button" name="submit" value="submit" class="bnt" id="subBtn"/>
      </form>
```